# How to keep Tooltip width

Tags: sass, tooltip, stenciljs

I have a tipic tooltip that shows on hovering a div, in this case is a bar. The width fits content and if the text in the tooltip is bigger than the width,just wrap and make a second line, which is good but the real problem is when the width of the bar is smaller than the width of the tooltip, tooltip moves to left for showing all text. I tried giving a min-width but this creates a scroll x.

How can I make that the tooltip show the text in one line and also always be displayed on its container?

The ideal process is: when I hover in any part of the bar, tooltip shows up at the top of the bar but in the x and y of the pointer. But not problem if it is always centered.

What happen when width is almost sufficient:
[image]

The worst case:
[image]

I know that this is about css but I'm not really good coding css. This is the scss and project is a StencilJS project.

scss code:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;

  .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

    /* tooltip box*/
    width: auto;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    background-color: #464646;
    isolation: isolate;

    /*tooltip positions */
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;

    /* tooltip text*/
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.71;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #fff;
  }

  /*show the tooltip*/
  &:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* show an arrow at the bottom*/
  .tooltiptext::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #464646 transparent transparent transparent;
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

What I need:
[image]

What happen when width is good:
[image]